# Android Here Maps classes missing

Tags: android, maps

Using here Android maps SDK. Registered at site, downloaded sdk BUT
can't find there classes that I really need:

```
MapLoader and MapLoader.Listener
```

and

```
installMapPackages(List<Integer> packageIdList)
```

Seems that SDK changed dramatically or what is the point?

https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-premium/topics/maps-offline.html

Comment: I ran into some of the same issues, for instance the route drawing examples for Android reference classes that are not included in the sdk (like CoreRouter).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to download SDK [here anroid sdk](https://developer.here.com/develop/mobile-sdks)